# How are security settings applied in ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: activemq-artemis

If you add security settings twice to the same address match, but with different roles, are the roles added to the previous roles or are they overwritten (or something else)?

For example, what kind of security settings would result from the following calls:

```
serverControl.addSecuritySettings("address1", "role1", "role1", "role1", "role1", "role1", "role1", "role1", "role1", "role1", "role1");
serverControl.addSecuritySettings("address1", "role2", "role2", "role2", "role2", "role2", "role2", "role2", "role2", "role2", "role2");
```

(ServerControl is ActiveMQServerControl.)

Is there a way to list the current security settings in ActiveMQ Artemis (programmatically or otherwise)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add security settings twice to the same address match, but with different roles the previous roles are overwritten.

Multiple roles can be added in a single call, e.g.:

```
serverControl.addSecuritySettings("address1", "role1, role2", "role1, role2", "role1, role2", "role1, role2", "role1, role2", "role1, role2", "role1, role2", "role1, role2", "role1, role2", "role1, role2");
```

Yo can check current security settings using ActiveMQServerControl.getRoles or  ActiveMQServerControl.getRolesAsJSON, i.e.

```
serverControl.getRolesAsJSON("address1")
```

Comment: Multiple roles can be added in a single call, e.g.: `serverControl.addSecuritySettings("address1", "role1, role2", "role1, role2", "role1, role2", "role1, role2", "role1, role2", "role1, role2", "role1, role2", "role1, role2", "role1, role2", "role1, role2");`

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a way to list all security settings (for all set address matches), but I suppose I can manage with that.

Comment: @JustinBertram thanks I'll update the answer with your suggestion